# Python : Render/Display JSON object in HTML using Flask

Tags: python, json, html, jinja2

I'm using a python dictionary/list and converting it into a JSON object. I'm trying to render this JSON record in HTML. I'm unable to display it in the html table. Let me know if I'm accessing the python dictionary in html the right way?

The code snippets is as below.

**Python code**

```
cursor=db.tweets.find({"$text": {"$search": value}})

json_docs = [json.dumps(document , default=json_util.default) for document in cursor ]
print(json_docs)
for jsondump in json_docs:
    x=json.loads(jsondump)
    print(x)
titles = [title for title in json_docs]
return render_template("searchResult.html", titles=titles)
```

**HTML code:**

```
<table border="1" style="width:50%">
   {% for title in titles %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ title }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="comment">
                View Data / Comments
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

</table>
```

**Sample data of json docs**

```
['{"source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/download/iphone&quot;&gt;Twitter for iPhone&lt;/a&gt;", "createdAt": "Wed, 31 Oct 2012 02:05:13 +0000", "latitude": 42.495299, "longitude": -92.329888, "twitterTweetId": 2.63e+17, "fromUser": "PrettyboiDenzel", "LanguageCode": "en", "id": 136269, "text": "Aye low key that bitch #hurricanesandy is up by Wisconsin .... If I\'\'m thinking right ..... THAT\'\'S CLOSE ASS HELL! That bitch sandy CRAYYY!", "_id": {"$oid": "565de24b39b758efe19d5b4c"}, "fromUserId": 57104215, "profileImageUrl": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2747557265/de3a171c1262c5a84016e6304c8eedc6_normal.jpeg", "fromUserName": "PrettyBoi\'\'Denzel"}']
```

**Value of x**

```
{'source': '&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/download/iphone&quot;&gt;Twitter for iPhone&lt;/a&gt;', 'latitude': 42.495299, 'longitude': -92.329888, 'twitterTweetId': 2.63e+17, 'fromUser': 'PrettyboiDenzel', 'LanguageCode': 'en', 'id': 136269, 'createdAt': 'Wed, 31 Oct 2012 02:05:13 +0000', '_id': {'$oid': '565de24b39b758efe19d5b4c'}, 'text': "Aye low key that bitch #hurricanesandy is up by Wisconsin .... If I''m thinking right ..... THAT''S CLOSE ASS HELL! That bitch sandy CRAYYY!", 'fromUserId': 57104215, 'profileImageUrl': 'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2747557265/de3a171c1262c5a84016e6304c8eedc6_normal.jpeg', 'fromUserName': "PrettyBoi''Denzel"}
```

Comment: what happens when you try to render that?  does the json look goofy?  as if it needs to be url encoded?

Comment: @MarcelWilson - I'm getting the complete json document in the table columns. eg : like {"source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/download..............}

Comment: What is `render_template`?  I think I'm missing something about what that function does to answer the question properly.

Comment: @MarcelWilson - render_template(_filename, **context)[source]
Renders a template and returns a response object.
Parameters: 
_filename – The template filename, related to the templates directory.
context – Keyword arguments used as variables in the rendered template. These will override values set in the request context.
Returns: 
A rendered template.

Comment: What library/package is it from? @shockwave

Comment: @MarcelWilson -  I'm using Flask Framework(Jinja2)

Comment: Waht data you want in the template?